# HTML5 canvas toDataURL sometimes returns "data:," instead of the image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have created a canvas with `document.createElement("canvas")`:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = width;     // width = 4000 or more
canvas.height = height;   // height = 5000 or more
```

Then I use `canvas.toDataURL()` to get its base64 string:

```
var str = canvas.toDataURL();
```

but the 'str' sometimes returns as `"data:,"`, with no image data in it. Just those six chars.

Sometimes it returns the correct string like `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAEGgAABPsCAYAAABg/aH3AAAgAElEQVR4XuzcQREAAAjDM..."`

I the `canvas.width` is too large ....

Comment: Does it occurs in each browsers ?

Comment: problem with data url limitation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156402/canvas-todataurl-for-large-canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to create a 2D context explicitly and then draw in it an empty shape, something like:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 4000;
canvas.height = 5000;
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0,0,0,0);
canvas.toDataURL();
```

Edit: It seems that your canvas contains too much data to be exported as a dataUri:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 400000000;
canvas.height = 500000000;
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0,0,0,0);
canvas.toDataURL();
// outputs : "data:,"
```

Comment: I have tried your method,and sadly it has no effect...what made me confusional is that, **sometimes wrong but sometimes correct**. I am new to html..in which situation does the canvas.toDataURL() returns **"data:,"** ?

Comment: I assume that when the image is empty, it can happen, but, i'll have to know in wich browser you got this issue. I tested on Chrome & Firefox and it never happenned.

Comment: I seems that you're canvas is too large, i tried this :

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 400000000;
    canvas.height = 500000000;
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,0,0);
    canvas.toDataURL();

And i had the same result : data:; In Google Chrome

It must be a limitation due to the maximum size of a dataUri.