# canvas.toDataURL() download size limit

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to download an entire canvas image using canvas.toDataURL().  The image is a map rendered on the canvas (Open Layers 3).

In Firefox I can use the following to download the map on the click of a link:

```
var exportPNGElement = document.getElementById('export_image_button');

if ('download' in exportPNGElement) {
    map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
    var canvas = event.context.canvas;
    exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
});

map.renderSync();

} else {
alert("Sorry, something went wrong during our attempt to create the image");
}
```

However in Chrome and Opera I'm hitting a size limit on the link.  I have to physically make the window smaller for the download to work.

There are size limit differences between browsers, Chrome is particularly limiting.  A similar post here (**over 2 years old now**) suggests an extensive server side workaround:

[canvas.toDataURL() for large canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156402/canvas-todataurl-for-large-canvas)

Is there a client side work around for this at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out `toBlob` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    exportPNGElement.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

browser support is not as awesome as `toDataURL` though. But Chrome and Firefox have it, so it solves your biggest issue. The mdn link above also has a polyfill based on `toDataURL`, so you get the best possible support.

Just in case you didn't know, you can also dramatically reduce the size using jpeg compression

```
exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: toBlob is quite browser limited [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) Just as an FYI. Depends on how critical IE/Safari is.