# Is it possible to programmatically detect size limit for data url?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, todataurl

I'm using javascript and html canvas to resize jpeg images. After resizing, I use `canvas.toDataURL` as the href attribute in an anchor tag in order to provide a link where users can download the resized images.

This works nicely up to a certain image size.

It seems that different browsers have different limits on the size of data urls as mentioned here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

In chrome, when I'm over the data url size limit, nothing happens when I click on the download link; no errors or anything (as far as I can tell).

Is there a some way to programmatically detect whether a data url is too large? Maybe some browser event that will show me whether clicking a download link failed?

Ideally, I'd like to detect whether the download was successful. When data urls are too large, I'd like to display an explanation to the end user describing how to right click on the image and choose "save as ...", which always seems to work.

Update 1:

It looks like using `canvas.toBlob` is the best workaround for now. Here's the api documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates how anchor href download links fail when using `toDataURL` for larger canvases, but `toBlob` seems to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/upgradingdave/c76q34ac/3/

Here are some related stackoverflow questions: 
[canvas.toDataURL() download size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480112/canvas-todataurl-download-size-limit)

[Data protocol URL size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations)

Comment: So Chrome silently fails ... When Chrome fails to deliver an oversized data url, does `console.log(theDataURL.length)` report zero length or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It looks like `theDataURL.length` returns the correct length even when the download fails, unfortunately.

Comment: Simple curiosity, what was the length of the string? Also you may want to try to set the dataURI as the src of an img while listening to its error event. Not sure if it fires, since I never produced such too long dataURI, but if it doesn't I guess it's a bug. (Last time I tried to reach these limits, (without trying the download) I was hitting the maxLength of a string before the maxLength of a dataURI, are you sure it's not something like memory hit?)

Comment: Arf, after testing myself, I found that this limit would be only for `<a>`  (the image loads fine but I get an uncatchable "Network Error" when using the download). What I would do is to play the safety by always converting your dataURI to a blob (or even better call `canvas.toBlob()` when available) and set the anchor's `href` to an objectURL. You shouldn't have this limitations. (I just tried with a 126MB output file and it works)

Comment: @Kaiido, yes that's the same behavior I'm seeing. I take a look at `canvas.toBlob()`. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, please see my updates, I think using `toBlob` is the best workaround. I added a jsfiddle. If you want to add an answer suggesting to use toBlob, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there doesn't seem to be any event letting you know if an anchor with the `download` attribute actually succeeded to download the resource.

But, the limitation you are facing seems to only concern this situation : an anchor element `<a>` with the `download` attribute.

The browser can handle way longer dataURI (I think that in most browsers the limitation is the same as the one for strings length). E.g, it can load it to `<img>` element, and more importantly in your case, it can process the dataURI string.

This is important because it allows you to convert this dataURI to a blob, then to create an [`object URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) from this blob. `object URL`'s URI are small and don't face this length limitation in anchors with `download` attribute.

So the best in your case is probably to directly use the `canvas.toBlob` method ([a polyfill is available on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Polyfill)), and to pass the `object URL`'s URI as the `href` of your anchor.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

img.onload = function(){
  var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = this.width*10;
  ctx.canvas.height = this.height*10;
  ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  // convert our canvas to a png blob 
  //  (for type use the second parameter, third is for quality if type is image/jpeg or image/webp)
  ctx.canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
     myAnchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    });
  // since we are dealing with use files, we absolutely need to revoke the ObjectURL as soon as possible
  var revokeURL = function(){
    // but we have to wait that the browser actually prepared the file to download
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      // we've waited one frame, it's seems to be enough
      URL.revokeObjectURL(this.href);
      this.href=null;
      });
    this.removeEventListener('click', revokeURL);
    };

  myAnchor.addEventListener('click', revokeURL);
  };

img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/';
```

```html
<a id="myAnchor" download="anAwesomeImage.png">download</a>
```

[**[ Live Demo ]**](https://jsfiddle.net/1a9otvut/) <sub>(since `download` attribute is blocked by some UA in SE-Snippets)</sub>

But note that even if the string representation (URI) of the `object URL` is short, it will actually take the size of your file in browser's memory, and so until you hard-refresh the page (clearing cache), or close the tab where you created this object URL. So you'll absolutely need to call `URL.revokeObjectURL()` to clear this space.
But, since there is no event to know if the downloading actually succeeded, you're stuck with the `onclick` event, which will fire **before** the file downloading occurred. From my tests, waiting for a single frame with `requestAnimationFrame` is enough, but I may be wrong.

---

And for the ones coming here with an other source than a canvas for their dataURI, there are already a lot of posts in SO about converting a dataURI to a blob, and you can just check the mdn polyfill provided above, they're doing it too.