# Attach a filename to a base64 image in a JSON file

Tags: image, angular, base64

I have an application that gets a JSON file via a web service. The JSON is fairly large, and represents a Person object, with typical properties such as first name, last name, title and image for example. The person's image is stored as a base64 field in the JSON. It is bound to an image tag using Angular. So for example, the HTML looks like this:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ person.fileImage }}">
```

When the end user right clicks on the image and chooses to save the image, the browser defaults to the name "download.jpg". What I need to do is name the image so that when the user right clicks and chooses to save, it gives a meaningful filename, e.g.:

todd.davis.jpg

I'm not sure how to make this happen. I've seen some solutions that use an anchor tag with a download="todd.jpg" parameter, but that is not working for me. I think it expects an actual URL and in this case, I don't really have one. The image data is just embedded in the JSON.

Is there a way to manipulate this so that I can add a name to the image for saving purposes?

Comment: The `<a download>` should work, even with an dataURL, except if it's too long (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781968/problems-downloading-big-filemax-15-mb-on-google-chrome/38845151#38845151) on chrome. Otherwise, no cross-browser way to set the filename for context menu's "Save As" (there might be an hack for FF but that's an hack)