# How to download text from javascript variable on all browsers?

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, download, cross-browser

I need a function that will download the string in a javascript variable into a text file(5-7MB). The function should work across browsers.

I've tried making such a download function, but it doesn't work on Chrome. FireFox opens the 'save' dialog box, but Chrome doesn't. Also, when I disable 'ask where to save file' in Chrome, it shows 'Failed - Network Error'. Since I'm doing everything locally, I don't see why this issue crops up.

```js
function download(filename, text) {
 var element = document.createElement('a');
 element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
 element.setAttribute('download', filename);

 element.style.display = 'none';
 document.body.appendChild(element);

 element.click();

 document.body.removeChild(element);

}
```

This doesn't open any dialog box for saving a file on Chrome(Version 76.0.3809.132). Same issue for Microsoft Edge(44.17763.1.0). I want it to work on all browsers, or at least work on FireFox and Chrome.

**Edit 1:** The Chrome issue seems to persist on other computers, so it can't be something wrong with the browser. I would also prefer to make my own function rather than use other projects(company issues).

**Edit 2:** It seems that the anchor size is limited to 2MB in Chrome. Is there a workaround for this? There are some answers that recommend using BLOB, but I'm not familiar with the concept. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I use this:  https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js , example for saving text to file is on repo: `var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");`

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38845151/6458902 may help you if your issue is related to the file size.

Comment: @Sackey Thanks for the link, it seems that there is no way to use the anchor for downloading files greater than 2MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple modification that now works on my FireFox and Chrome. It uses BLOB to get around the anchor size limit. It still doesn't work on Microsoft Edge though.

```js
function download(filename, text, type="text/plain") {
  // Create an invisible A element
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(a);

  // Set the HREF to a Blob representation of the data to be downloaded
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([text], { type })
  );

  // Use download attribute to set set desired file name
  a.setAttribute("download", filename);

  // Trigger the download by simulating click
  a.click();

  // Cleanup
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this icon appears in your address bar

[image: Disabled automatic downloads picture]

then check your Chrome config [to enable automatic downloads](http://chrome://settings/content/automaticDownloads).

Comment: The download icon is not visible on the browser.