# Feature Detection: URL Length

Tags: javascript, html, browser

How can you detect the max supported length of a URL in a browser using Javascript?

There are 2 ways to open a new tab with specific html:

1. `var w = window.open(); w.document.write(html)`
2. `var w = window.open('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html))`

The benefit of the latter is that the page can be refreshed, be bookmarked, and appear in history, but IE doesn't support urls over 2047 characters.

I could just check whether I'm in IE or not, but feature detection is much better - and maybe other browsers would also break if the url is too long. Is there a way to detect when I can open a window with specific content using a data protocol URI vs when I need to write it using JS?

Comment: sort of related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918075/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-detect-size-limit-for-data-url

Comment: Looks promising but he ended up taking a different tack.

Comment: @epascarello - I mean that the author of that question started with a question similar to mine, but he ended up going a different direction so the answers there don't apply to what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah, i misread your comment...