# p5.js saveCanvas() fails with "Network error" in Google Chrome unless the console is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, processing, processing.js, p5.js

I've written a small sketch in p5.js that finishes by saving a snapshot of the canvas using the `saveCanvas()` method.

When I have the console open, things happen exactly as I would expect (a file with the name I provide is saved to the Downloads folder). However, if I close the developer console, I see "download, Failed - Network error."

This issue only seems to happen in Chrome. I have been able to run the sketch successfully using Safari and Firefox with no consoles open.

I have already removed any reference to `console` in my code (such as `console.log()`).

Comment: Can you please post a link to an example that shows the problem, preferably a CodePen or JSFiddle?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known restriction in chrome's max-length for anchor's `href`.

The usual [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918075/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-detect-size-limit-for-data-url/36951356) is to request an Blob, and then create a blobURI instead of an dataURI, or to convert the data-URI to a Blob and a blobURI.

But since you are using p5.js 's method, they should do it, so for a real fix, you'll have to [post an issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues) on their tracker.

For a workaround, you can still access yourself the canvas element,

```
var canvas = createCanvas(w, h);
var canvasElt = canvas.elt;
```

call its [`toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method, then use something like [*FileSaver.js*](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to get the same result.