# html download attribute not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I allow the user to download a .json file using:

```
function downloadObjectAsJson(exportObj, exportName){
  var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + 
  encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(exportObj));
  var downloadAnchorNode = document.createElement('a');
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
  downloadAnchorNode.setAttribute("download", exportName + ".ipynb");
  downloadAnchorNode.click();
  downloadAnchorNode.remove();
}
```

This works perfectly in Safari, but in Chrome I get the following popup message:

**There is no application set to open the document**

Comment: Does it make a difference if you append it to the DOM?

Comment: also, I think your content type is wrong

Comment: Does this work for you? [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e39xz0t2/) Also do you have the "Always open files of this type" checked in Chrome?

Comment: Same problem. The popup appears.

Comment: @epascarello my content type is set to json, which is correct.

Comment: @Cybernetic that is not the correct content type for JSON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type

Comment: data:text/json is not the right content type for json?

Comment: and keep in mind, this works perfectly in Safari

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but do you have the program required to open up a `.ipynb` file?

Comment: Yes, jupyter notebooks. As I said, this works in safari so it has to be an issue with Chrome. Their last update broke the ability to download ipynb files. I am now using JSZIP to zip the file first and it works fine.

Comment: How big was the produced data: URL? Could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918075/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-detect-size-limit-for-data-url/36951356#36951356

Answer (score -1):

Check your network tab, your network call might get canceled as the node is now not available