# HTML5: Anchor href is too big to trigger download attribute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I'm making a sending file function of a chatroom. The language I'm using is nodejs (socket.io) and js.

The way I work it out is to

1. use javacript `fileReader` to read a file in chrunks as `ArrayBuffer`, and transfer the pieces to server, server collects the data until all data is collected.
2. Sever send `ArrayBuffer` back to the other clients.
3. On the clientside, convert `ArrayBuffer` to `base64String`, and add prefix depends on the MIME type such as `data:application/pdf;base64,`.
4. Insert this `base64String` to a `<a href='{thisBase64String}' download></a>`.

**Currently, it only works on those pdf files whose size are less than 2MB, the `download` attribute doesn't work on fileSize over 10MB.**

My guess is the size of href too long causing the problem, any idea to fix this problem?

I know probably I can use `fs.write` to print out the uploaded file first, then link to the directory. But since it is a chatroom, I wish I can make everything on the air. There is no need spending time to maintain the server, isn't it?

Comment: It'd be better to place that file somewhere in public directory of your web server ( save it with node when you get all chunks from client ) ,  and then just send them a short link

Comment: @MarkoMackic Thank you for your suggestion, though I mentioned this advice in the question already. This problem can be answered by 'Data protocol URL size limitations', so I can do nothing about the URL limitations, which makes your advice the only way that can work for me.

Comment: The previous dupe target was not related to your issue whatsoever. I changed it to two other answers that will give you a real solution: don't use a fileReader at all, create simply a blobURI from your Blob, and set your href to this blobURI. No size limit now.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, that was a very smart solution, appreciate that! Just that I don't understand why do we need to `requestAnimationFrame()` before `revokeURL()` in your answer of [Is it possible to programmatically detect size limit for data url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918075/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-detect-size-limit-for-data-url)

Comment: @Kaiido Can we also use a similar solution to generate a objectURL href for pdf?

Comment: Oh the rAF was just a way to ensure there has been enough tome for the download to begin. But that can probably be done in better ways actually.