# Downloading canvas image using toBlob

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to download a large canvas image (several thousand pixels height and width) on the click of a button using `toBlob` in the following code, which doesn't seem to work:

```
document.getElementById("download_button").onclick = function() {

  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = "image.png";

  canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(blob);
  },'image/png');

  console.log(link.href);
  link.click();

}
```

`console.log(blob)` in the callback function returns: `Blob {size: 64452, type: "image/png"}`

But `console.log(link.href)` returns nothing.

Am I not using `.createObjectURL` correctly?

I used to work with `toDataURL`, but it stopped working above a certain canvas size. And this post [canvas.toDataURL() download size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480112/canvas-todataurl-download-size-limit) suggested to try `toBlob`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your code is fine.. just use it at the right time   :)

```
 canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(blob);
    console.log(link.href); // this line should be here
  },'image/png');
```

Comment: Right, thanks ! 
It works correctly with `console.log(link.href);` and `link.click();` inside the callback function.

Comment: @ymz why is that though? I thought that would only be the case if .href was a custom property being added to the link element but it wasnt, yet the link element was defined in the event function scope too so should be accessible too or is it because it's nested within another function?

Comment: @ymz I just tried a little something to attempt to test it and this is what I get:
`var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = "image.png";
function test() {
 link.href = "#Test";
 console.log(link.href);
}`
result: "image.png"

Comment: in addition, my first thought is that link.href shouldn't be accessible outside of that function or atleast, return "image.png" based on the above behavior strangely enough, yet link.href outside of the function scope gives an empty string.

Comment: @brandito I know this is very late, but the reason is that canvas.toBlob is asynchronous. The code is saying "start converting to a blob, and run this function when done", and continues immediately to clicking a link before the blob is finishing converting.

Answer (score 13):

My solution to the problem:

```
async function getImage({
  canvas,
  width,
  height,
  mime = 'image/jpeg',
  quality = 0.8,
}) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    tmpCanvas.width = width;
    tmpCanvas.height = height;

    const ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(
      canvas,
      0,
      0,
      canvas.width,
      canvas.height,
      0,
      0,
      width,
      height,
    );

    tmpCanvas.toBlob(resolve, mime, quality);
  });
}

const photo = await getImage({ canvas, width: 500, height: 500 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also create a custom prototype to get an equivalent to `canvas.toDataURL()`

```js
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toObjectURL = async function(
  mimeType = "image/jpeg",
  quality = 0.85
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.toBlob(
      (blob) => {
        if (!blob) {
          reject("Error creating blob");
          return;
        }

        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        resolve(blobUrl);
      },
      mimeType,
      quality
    );
  });
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<img id="imgBlob" src="" alt="">
<img id="imgUrl" src="" alt="">

<p><a id="linkObjectUrl" href="" download="image.jpg">Download img (object URL)</a> | <a id="linkDataUrl" href="" download="image.webp">Download img (data URL)</a></p>

<script>
  // example canvas
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async(e) => {

    // draw example on canvas
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200";
    await img.decode();
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // get object URL
    let quality = 0.5;
    let objectUrl = await canvas.toObjectURL("image/jpeg", quality);
    let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp", quality);

    // set object URLs
    linkObjectUrl.href = objectUrl;
    linkDataUrl.href = dataUrl;

    // apply to image elements
    imgBlob.src = objectUrl;
    imgUrl.src = dataUrl;

  })
</script>
```

#### Usage

The method needs to be called in a **async** function.

```
let objectUrl = await canvas.toObjectURL("image/jpeg", quality);
```

Download links don't work in SO snippets.
See also [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ZEwqPzw?editors=1010)