# Canvas.toBlob() not downloading some PNGs and very high quality JPGs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been using this code to download images from a canvas:

```
function fileSave1() 
{
    var dataURL = "";
    var canvasSave = document.getElementById("cSave");
    if (document.getElementById("png").checked == true) dataURL = canvasSave.toDataURL(); // PNG is default 
    if (document.getElementById("jpg").checked == true) dataURL = canvasSave.toDataURL('image/jpeg', Number(document.getElementById("quality").value) / 100); // JPG with Quality Setting requires 2 arguments 
    //var start = dataURL.indexOf(";"); //start point will vary based on image/png (9 characters) vs image/jpeg (10 characters) 
    //dataURL = dataURL.slice(start); 
    //dataURL = "data:application/octet-stream" + dataURL; 
    if (document.getElementById("jpg").checked == true) document.getElementById("afterCanvas2").innerHTML = '<a download="new_image.jpg" href='+ dataURL +'>Save New JPG with a Quality Setting of ' + document.getElementById("quality").value + ' </a>';
    if (document.getElementById("png").checked == true) document.getElementById("afterCanvas2").innerHTML = '<a download="new_image.png" href='+ dataURL +'>Save New Full Quality PNG</a>';
}
```

However, in Chrome, it is not downloading some PNGs and very high quality JPGs. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480112/canvas-todataurl-download-size-limit) suggests the problem is that the file sizes are too large, and suggests canvas.toBlob() as the workaround. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567511/downloading-canvas-image-using-toblob?noredirect=1&lq=1) has a code sample, but I am having trouble adapting it to my code.

I would deeply appreciate assistance with the proper syntax.

Thank you

EDIT: The code that failed:

```
        function fileSave1()
        {

            var canvas = document.getElementById('cSave');

            canvas.toBlob(function(blob)
            {
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                url.onload = function() 
                {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                };

            });

          document.getElementById("afterCanvas2").innerHTML = '<a download="new_image.png" href='+ url +'>Save New Full Quality PNG</a>';    

        }
```

Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined at fileSave1.

Thank you

Comment: "...`canvas.toBlob()` as the workaround...I am having trouble adapting it to my code." I agree, using a blob might fix it. Can we see the code you wrote to do that?

Comment: I already deleted it. Let me see if I can undo the delete in Notepad++.

Comment: @Sidney A power surge closed Notepad++, I have re-written the code and added it to the original post as an edit. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest changing the topic to "Canvas.toDataURL() not downloading some PNGs and very high quality JPGs" since that is the issue. Canvas.toBlob() is the fix, but it's not working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious why you're trying to attach an `onload` handler to the URL in the second code snippet? That's not part of the accepted answer from the post you linked.

It looks like the second code snippet almost works, but there are a few things out of place.

I believe this will work:

```
function fileSave1() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('cSave');

  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    const anchor = document.createElement('a')
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    anchor.href = url
    anchor.download = 'canvas.png'
    document.body.appendChild(anchor)
    anchor.click()
    document.body.removeChild(anchor)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
  }, 'image/png')
}
```

Notice that it `click()`'s the anchor element as soon as the blob is ready, so calling the function `fileSave1()` will immediately download the file, instead of adding an anchor to the document for the user to click. You could change this behavior if you want.

Comment: I'm adapting this to my page now Sidney.  I'll update the post with the result. Thank you

Comment: This is going to work.  I adapted to using a download link, just need to add PNG vs JPG and add JPG Quality.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: I forgot to mark this as the answer.  Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help :)