# Html2canvas take high quality screen shot with high "SCALE"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, html2canvas

I change the screenshot quality by change the `scale`, for high quality I use the high scale,
it works for quality that the image size will be less than `15MB` and for the higher quality it, not works, actually when the screenshot takes an image by more than 15 MB I can't do anything by that image data.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('body').click(function(event) {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("content"), {
      scale: 5.5,
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      // Export the canvas to its data URI representation
      var base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      // console.log(base64image);
      $('.entry-content').after(`
        <img src="` + base64image + `" alt="">
      `);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480112/canvas-todataurl-download-size-limit

Comment: @MatusJurika Thanks for your guide,But I don't want to change any thing , I just want to create a screen shot more the 15MB and download it.

Comment: please check `console.log(base64image);` for both images more than 15MB as well as for images less than 15MB then let me know

Comment: It is very long and can't handle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution
It is related to the `php.ini` setting
I change `PHP.ini` configuration as bellow and know I can take screenshot up to `90 MB` by increasing the `scale` value.

`post_max_size=1024M`

`upload_max_filesize=2048M`

If not working please add these codes to `functions.php` file

```
@ini_set('upload_max_size','256M');
@ini_set('post_max_size','256M');
@ini_set('max_execution_time','30000');
@ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```